# How to access a column in a dataframe which is stored in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, yahoo-finance

So I have a dictionary called "Stock" in which I've stored multiple Dataframes with the data of stocks, gathered from Yahoo Finance.

eg. so `print(Stock["TSLA"])` is:

| Date | High | Low | ... | Volume | Adj Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-08-19 | 382.200012 | 368.242004 | ... | 61026500.0 | 375.705994 |
| 2020-08-20 | 404.398010 | 371.411987 | ... | 103059000.0 | 400.365997 |
| 2020-08-21 | 419.097992 | 405.010010 | ... | 107448000.0 | 409.996002 |
| 2020-08-24 | 425.799988 | 385.503998 | ... | 100318000.0 | 402.839996 |
| 2020-08-25 | 405.589996 | 393.600006 | ... | 53294500.0 | 404.667999 |
| 2021-01-25 | 900.400024 | 838.820007 | ... | 41173400.0 | 880.799988 |
| 2021-01-26 | 895.900024 | 871.599976 | ... | 23131600.0 | 883.090027 |
| 2021-01-27 | 891.500000 | 858.659973 | ... | 27334000.0 | 864.159973 |
| 2021-01-28 | 848.000000 | 801.000000 | ... | 26378000.0 | 835.429993 |
| 2021-01-29 | 842.409973 | 780.099976 | ... | 34758800.0 | 793.530029 |

Now I want to access just the "Adj Close" column to get only:

| Adj Close |
| --- |
| 375.705994 |
| 400.365997 |
| 409.996002 |
| etc. |

I have tried:

```
print(Stock["TSLA"]["Adj Close"])
```

However, this does not work and gives me an Error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Additionally I want to get the length (number of rows) of the "Adj Close" column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that Stock["TSLA"] is dataframe? It looks like it is a list. Your code should work if it is a dataframe. What is the result of type(Stock["TSLA"])?

Comment: type(Stock["TSLA"]) returns <class 'list'>, although, I gathered the data in a for loop with `Stock[i].append(web.DataReader("TSLA", "yahoo", ...))` (with "i" being the tickersymbols), which should be a dataframe in my understanding. `print(Stock["TSLA"])` also prints it like a dataframe and not like a list.

Comment: It is indeed a list. How do I convert it to a dataframe? When I try `Stock["TSLA"] = pd.DataFrame(Stock["TSLA"])` I get an empty Dataframe.

Comment: This is a very different question. You must provide some sample of your original data. You would better open a new question